# VB.net - PointToScreen/ClientRectangle.Location not working on Windows 10 - wrong locations

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, screenshot

I have used this subroutine for screen capture of forms on Windows 7 with VS 2019. When I started using this on Windows 10, the locations are messed up. The left of the Form is a lot of pixels to the right of the image captured. Is there a good solution or workaround which does not need a lot of new code?

...
Sub SaveFromScreen(frm As Form, filn As String)

```
Dim img As New Bitmap(frm.ClientSize.Width, frm.ClientSize.Height)

Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    gr.CopyFromScreen(frm.PointToScreen(frm.ClientRectangle.Location), Point.Empty, frm.ClientSize)
End Using

img.Save(filn, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

End Sub
...

Then it is called simply as

...
Call SaveFromScreen(Me, filN)
...

Comment: What .Net version? If you're using .Net Framework, you need to make your app DpiAware (`PerMonitorV2`); start from here: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)

Comment: I uncommented this

...
`
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
`
...

But now the form sizes are messed up.

Comment: You didn't specify the .Net version in use. If you're targeting .Net Framework, you need at least v.4.7.2, but you should target v. 4.8 AND you need to modify `app.config` (not `app.manifest`) to set, as mentioned, the `PerMonitorV2` DpiAwareness mode -- Then, set `AutoScaleMode = Dpi` in your Forms and UserControls. Select a Font that is designed for this, as `Segoe UI` or `Microsoft YaHei UI` (the `UI` suffix has a precise meaning) -- Design your application at 100% scale -- There is most probably something to fix in the layout of your Forms. Nested containers can help you a lot

Comment: I have .NET Framework v.4.8. 

Should I again put the previous xml code in comments in app.manifest?

Changing the font could be a large task now unless I can write some code to do that (and then check that there is enough space for the text in the controls).

Comment: What you have to do in `app.config` is described in the documentation I've linked in my first comment. In `app.manifest` you have to declare the compatibility with the Windows System you plan to support (uncomment all that apply) -- Usually - if not otherwise specified - Controls inherit the Font from their Parent, so most of the time changing the Top Level Control's (the Form) Font also changes the Font of all child Controls (as mentioned, some redefinition of the existing layout is most probably needed, as always happens when key layout features are modified)

Comment: Inspite of all this help and changes in app.manifest and app.config, I am not able to get dpiAwareness. Is it easy to go back to .NET framework 4.2? 

I have added 
  <System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
    <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
  </System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
to app.config
and
uncommented
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
in app.manifest, besides
     <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
   </windowsSettings>
still not working.

Comment: I don't know what `.NET Framework 4.2`. Do you mean `.NET Framework 4.7.2`? Something else? You need `4.7.2`+ -- You only set the DpiAwareness mode in `app.config`, not in `app.manifest`, where you instead, as already mentioned, you simply uncomment the supported System versions -- If you set something related to DpiAwareness in `app.manifest`, you override (an render mute) what's in `app.config`, but `app.manifest` is the *older* method and has less options. You shouldn't use it

Comment: You could also move to .Net 6+, where DpiAwareness is automatic, so you don't need to do anything, except you can set `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>` in your Project file, to override the default `SystemAware` mode

Comment: What do I have to do to move to .Net 6+? Sorry, I am just a beginner and don't know too many basic things.

Setting dpiAwareness in app.config has not helped solve the problem. I have another project which seems to be dpiAware. It was compiled on Windows 7 about a year ago. That probably had a earlier .NET framework.

I tried to find which .NET version I have from regedit but I see only folders upto v4.0. I tried to check which Windows 10 Home release I have but can't figure out. It says OS build 19045.2251, and Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0.

Comment: To target .Net 6, you need Visual Studio 2022 -- I don't know why the DpiAwareness you have doesn't appear to be working, because I don't know what you have actually done. If `Form.PointToScreen(Form.ClientRectangle.Location)` returns wrong coordinates, then your app is not DpiAware. When you create a new Bitmap, right after, verify its properties, check the Dpi setting: if it's 96 and instead your Screen is scaled or it uses a different Dpi value, then you are in virtual mode. If instead the Dpi property value matches the Screen's Dpi, it's DpiAware and the problem is somewhere else

Comment: It is clear that the app is not dpiAware.
1, I have downloaded VS 2022.
2, Dim img As New Bitmap(frm.ClientSize.Width, frm.ClientSize.Height) is returning the wrong size as well.
Should VS 2022 solve the problem? Do I have to reset app manifest and config?